# What is AngularJS uibmodal resolve arguement?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am very new new in angularJS and i am not getting what does `resolve` and `scope` do in uibModel...

I notice, if you i dont use `resolve` or `scope` in open method argument, yet my code works nice...

My Question, Why people user `scope` and `resolve`? what is use-case of these two argument?

Thanks for your time..

Comment: I read it before and screwed up with its documentation... I am not getting only scope and resolve usecase

Comment: My Question, why should i use scope in uibmodel? and should i use resolve?

Comment: You should use resolve to pass data from the opening controller to the opened modal controller, as shown in the example. You should use scope if you want the parent scope of the modal controller to be different from the root scope, as the documentation explains.